How to delete the user IDs matched from this query in WordPress in SQL?
I have a query that finds all Dealers without orders like so:
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%dealer%') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_order_count' AND meta_value > 0)

The query retrieves a set of User IDs. I'm struggling to find how to delete users in bulk by their user ID.
What's the best way to delete these users using SQL?

Here is one way to do it. Let me know if you encounter an issue.
-- Step 1: Backup your database

-- Step 2: Create a temporary table to store user_ids

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_users_to_delete` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned
);

-- Step 3: Insert the user_ids into the temporary table

INSERT INTO `temp_users_to_delete` (`user_id`)
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%dealer%') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_order_count' AND `meta_value` > 0);

-- Step 4: Delete the users from wp_users

DELETE FROM `wp_users`
WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `temp_users_to_delete`);

-- Step 5: Delete the user meta from wp_usermeta

DELETE FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `temp_users_to_delete`);

-- Step 6: Drop the temporary table

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_users_to_delete`;

